# How to prevent special characters copy paste on number field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to copy paste only numbers in 'number field'. If I didn't prevent copy paste I can copy the `'e','+','-'` and `'.'` in the number field. In the number field, I can type those characters so I have used another script. I want to type and copy paste only numbers.

Please check the code:

```js
jQuery("#otp_number").bind("cut copy paste", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default behaviour 
});
document.querySelector("#otp_number").addEventListener("keypress", function(evt) {
  if (evt.which != 8 && evt.which != 0 && evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
OTP: <input type="number" id="otp_number" data-ignorepaste="" />
```

Comment: Don't use `bind`, use `on` instead. Also, `e.which` is deprecated and should not be used any more. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable copy paste of alphabets in text field using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855708/disable-copy-paste-of-alphabets-in-text-field-using-jquery)

Comment: You can use  contextmenu to disable part of page

Comment: Can you the users paste every thing? It seems a little bit irrational that users paste some characters like `+`. Maybe you want remove invalid characters from input when they paste a string includes these characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery("#otp_number").on("paste", function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text').match(/[^\d]/))
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default behaviour 
})
.on("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 0 && e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) 
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

You don't need to restrict the copy or cut actions. It is quite enough to apply a test on the paste event. The event is prevented only when a non-numeric character is found in the clipboard that is about to be pasted.

I haven't had the time to test this, so, please, try and improve where necessary.

**Edit:**

I was surprised that my original answer got so much positive feedback. However, here is an alternative version which I believe is a bit more tolerant and user-friendly. It allows the input of any conceivable character at first (per input or paste) and removes all *non-numerical* characters afterwards:

```js
jQuery("#otp_number").on("paste keyup",function(e){
   $(this).val(this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,''))  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="other" placeholder="anything"><br>
<input type="text" id="otp_number" placeholder="numbers only">
```

Comment: Note that your second solution wouldn't work with input[type="number"]: an invalid value would return `""`.

Comment: @Kaiido: yes, I noticed that myself and used the input type "text" instead which I is definitely more suitable for this use case.

Comment: But I guess OP was willing to use type=number, at least for the enhanced UI.

Comment: Well, I hope OP chooses whatever version he likes best. Both should be working in their own way ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to access the content of the clipboard before it gets added to your input.

To do this, you would normally look into the [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object that is being passed along the [ClipboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent).clipboardData property.
But all browsers don't support this, so you'll also have to handle special IE case which exposes it on the global Window object.

Note that I had to modify a bit your onkeypress handler so it doesn't block ctrl + v combinations, but IMO this function would probably benefit from a full refactoring anyway...

```js
jQuery("#otp_number").on("paste", function(e) {
  var dT = e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  var text = dT.getData('text');
  if(parseInt(text) !== +text) { // allow only Ints
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default behaviour 
  }
});

// that one would probably need some refactoring...
document.querySelector("#otp_number").addEventListener("keypress", function(evt) {
  if(!evt.ctrlKey && !evt.metaKey && // don't block ctrl + v
    evt.which != 8 && evt.which != 0 && (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
OTP: <input type="number" id="otp_number" data-ignorepaste="" />
```